# How do I show that the language {w|M_w accepts 0x iff it accepts 1x} is not recursive?

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines

I need to show that L = {w|M_w accepts 1x iff it accepts 0x} is not recursive

I believe this should be a simple application of Rice's Theorem that states that for any nontrivial property P of recursively enumerable languages, {w | M_w is a Turing Machine and L(M_w) is in P} is not recursive. I am a bit unsure of this because I am not too sure what constitutes as a property; moreover, I do not know how to show that it is specifically a property of recursively enumerable languages, either.

Answer (score 0):

> I am a bit unsure of this because I am not too sure what constitutes as a property;

For the purposes of Rice's theorem, a property is any logical statement (proposition, predicate, etc.) about some language which is either true or false for that language. A property is nontrivial if the statement is neither tautological nor contradictory: that is, it is nontrivial if it is true of some languages but not others. The property "|L| < 0" is contradictory and is therefore a trivial property; "|L| >= 0" is tautological and therefore a trivial property; "|L| = 0" is a nontrivial property.

> moreover, I do not know how to show that it is specifically a property of recursively enumerable languages, either.

Recursively enumerable languages are also "just languages" and their properties are also the properties of "just languages". They are sets of strings and their properties all involve what strings are in them. Do not get hung up on whether a particular property of languages is a property of recursively-enumerable languages: it is. Even if it were not, a proof using Rice's Theorem isn't affected: if the property is known not to apply to recursively-enumerable languages and to be nontrivial, then it is known the language is not recursive anyway - Rice's Theorem isn't even necessary.